# How To Redirect mydomain.com To myotherdomain.com/wordpress/website/

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect

I have a domain name **mydomain.com**
I also have a website hosted at **myotherdomain.com/wordpress/website/**

What I want is when someone enters **mydomain.com/my_post/** into the browser, it shows them the content from **myotherdomain.com/wordpress/website/my_post/** preserving the original URL in the address toolbar.

I guess it is **.htaccess** job, but I don't know a thing about how to handle it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

here is sample code for you

```
RewriteRule ^my_post/index.php http://myotherdomain.com/wordpress/website/my_post/\/ [R=301,L]
```

hope this will help you. thanks

Comment: what if I want to redirect **mydomain.com** root (with no *my_post/blahblah*) to **myotherdomain.com/wp/website/** ?

Comment: it works! but the thing is I want to preserve the initial *mydomain.com* URL. Right now URL is changed to *myotherdomain.com/wp/whatever/* and I want it to keep the initial. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

You might have to use something like

Which will redirect http://example.com/file.html to http://example.com/folder1/file.html:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !folder1
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/folder1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

For complete guide https://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/85/Using+.htaccess+rewrite+rules#gs

**[UPDATED]**

If I am correct this should work give a try.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example1\.com  [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  http://www.example2.com/folder1/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: The thing is in my case I have two different domain names. Is it possible to do the same but with example1.com and example2.com?

Answer (score 0):

> RewriteEngine On
>
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://myotherdomain.com/wordpress/website/my_post/ [QSA,L]

Comment: Thanks ... redirect now works well! But I need to preserve *mydomain.com* in the browser address input. Right now when I enter *mydomain.com* the address changes to *myotherdomain.com/wordpress/website/* and I want it to remain *mydomain.com*. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an index.html with this code:

```
<div id="iFrame1" style="position:absolute; left:0px; top:0px; z-index:0">
<iframe name="iFrame1" width="{Differs}%" height="100%" src="http://myotherdomain.com/wordpress/website/my_post/" scrolling="yes" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
```

Here is an example of GasBuddies's site:

```
<div id="iFrame1" style="position:absolute; left:0px; top:0px; z-index:0">
<iframe name="iFrame1" width="455%" height="100%" src="http://gasbuddy.com/" scrolling="yes" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
```